# str_replace problem in php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I want to strip all spaces that are not between two words? The script says it all:)

```
$string = "              bah bah    bah  ";
$string = str_replace("/w /w", "+", $string);
// i want string to look like this:
$string = "bah+bah+bah";
```

The idea is that i want to get rid of all unnecessary spaces(not only at the beginning and end)

Comment: Will you use this inside a URL ?

Comment: after i delete the spaces i want to explode it (but that is done already)

Comment: So the str_replace is the best for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just trim whitespace and use `urlencode()` to convert the interior spaces to `+`?  If you have other characters which cannot tolerate being url encoded, this will not work.  But we don't know your full requirements.

```
urlencode(trim($string));


$string = "              bah bah";
echo urlencode(trim($string));

// bah+bah
```

Comment: this is what i get whit this: "+++++++++++bah+bah".. i am looking for the simplest way to get this: "bah+bah";

Comment: @zolee3003 Are you sure you included the `trim()` inside `urlencode()`? This works fine for me.

Comment: the idea is that i want to delete all unnecessary spaces

Answer (score 4):

[trim](http://php.net/trim) will remove the whitespace at the beginning and end:

```
$string = trim($string);
echo str_replace(" ", "+", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = str_replace("/w /w", "+", trim($string));
```

trim() deletes all unnecessary spaces